# Lua String Data to Table

Tags: regex, string, lua, lua-table

I am trying to parse String Data to Lua Table. Tried a few Lua string Library functions but had no luck.

The String Data Returned from the server looks like this

```
E000: Success
AOS               1.5.1.1
Switched Rack PDU 1.2.0.2 
Model:            abc3245
Name:             Test Device
Location:         Unknown
Contact:          Unknown
Present Outlets:  16
Switched Outlets: 16
Metered Outlets:  0
Max Current:      32 A A
Present Phases:   1
Metered Phases:   1
Metered Banks:    2
Uptime:           1 Day 9 Hours 22 Minutes
Network Link:     Link Active
```

I am trying to achieve Table Key Value Pair like

```
DataTable = {["E000"]= "Sucess",["AOS"]= "1.5.1.1"}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At first it might seem colon-delimited, but for `AOS` and `Switched Rack PDU` it isn't. Then you might try delimiting it by the first space, but the words contain spaces. You might also try using the fact that it appears to be aligned, but this isn't the case for `E000`. Is this really the format you're getting the data in?

Comment: there is no clear structure for defining delimiters